# Show x & y values in same location in label where I clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to display a label where I clicked on the screen.Mean at the same location where I clicked, a label generates & show me the x & y position in jquery/javascript.Please how to do this?

```
$(function() 
    {
      $("#image_canvas").click(function(e) 
      {
        console.log(file);
        var offset    = $(this).offset();
        var x_axis    = (e.pageX - offset.left);
        var y_axis    = (e.pageY - offset.top);

        **//Here I want to generate label on the x_axis & y_axis position.**

        console.log("X :" + x_axis + " Y:" + y_axis);
});
```

Comment: Do you have any code to show what you have tried? You can try [creating a minimal, verifiable and concrete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to demonstrate your efforts so far, and show us where you got stuck and need help with.

Comment: @Terry,please check the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your code is correctly getting the `x` and `y` you could add a div into the html, something like

```
<div id='js-label'></div>
```

initially hide it off screen with css

```
#js-label{
  opacity:0;
  left:-500px;
  top:-500px;
  position:absolute;
   z-index:2;
}
```

Then in your code:

```
    $(function() {
          $("#image_canvas").click(function(e) {
            console.log(file);
            var offset    = $(this).offset();
            var x_axis    = (e.pageX - offset.left);
            var y_axis    = (e.pageY - offset.top);

            $('#js-label').html("X :" + x_axis + " Y:" + y_axis);
            $('#js-label').css({'top' : y_axis, 'left' : x_axis, 'opacity' : 1});        
    });
});
```

Another option would be to use either jquery's `show()` and `hide()` methods to display/hide the label/message.

A better approach would be to use jquery `addClass()` and use css transitions to handle the show/hide with animations

Comment: Thank You sir.It fixed my issue.

Comment: ,sir how to hide the js-label when I move the mouse out side the div specified.Actually I did it on mousemove instead of click.